# Show that the straight line $3x-5y=2z$, $3x+5y=2$ lie entirely on the paraboloid $9x^2-25y^2=4z$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

Show that the straight line $3x-5y=2z$, $3x+5y=2$ lie entirely on the paraboloid $9x^2-25y^2=4z$.

Attempt

The equation  $$9x^2-25y^2=4z$$ can be written as  $$3x-5y=2\lambda z, ~~3x+5y=\frac{2}{\lambda }.$$ If it is a generator, it lies entirely on the given surface.

If a point is given in the question through which the generator passes, then I can easyly find $\lambda $, but it is not given. How to solve it.

Comment: paraboloid or hyperboloid?

Comment: @imranfat paraboloid

Comment: None of what you call "straight lines" is a straight line, but rather planes as we're in three-dimensional space. What did you **really** mean to ask?

Comment: @DonAntonio Edited. and is replaced by ,. The Straight line is the line of intersection of two planes.

Comment: I can't see it "edited", yet...

Comment: @DonAntonio The question is ::: Show that the straight line $3x-5y=2z$, $3x+5y=2$ lie entirely on the paraboloid $9x^2-25y^2=4z$.

Comment: @rama_ran That is, to say the least, very  confusing, and perhaps even wrong. Perhaps you meant : "show that **the intersection line** of the planes..."?

Comment: On the other hand, if you give the question-asker the benefit of the doubt... there's only (at most) one sensible interpretation of a "line" defined by two planes.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes you are right, the intersection line of the planes

Comment: @BadamBaplan That's trivial, but not what a reader will understand when reading the question's title: it is written there "the line", and then there are the equations of two planes...one could *guess* that it is meant "the intersection line", but this doesn't follow nor it is trivially understood of what is written there.

Comment: Try $\lambda=1$

Comment: It is definitely not correct to call this surface plainly a paraboloid: it should be called **hyperbolic paraboloid.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ lie on the intersection of the planes

\begin{align}3x-5y&=2z\\3x+5y&=2\end{align}

If we multiply the equations we get $$(3x_0-5y_0)(3x_0+5y_0) = 4z_0 \implies 9x_0^2-25y_0^2=4z_0$$

which implies that $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ lies on $$9x^2-25y^2=4z.$$

Answer (score 3):

Use $z$ as independent variable on the line $\ell$. This means solving
$$\eqalign{3x-5y&=2z\cr 3x+5y&=2\cr}$$
for $x$ and $y$. The result is $x={1\over3}(1+z)$, $\>y={1\over5}(1-z)$. It follows that in all points of $\ell$ we have
$$9x^2-25y^2=(1+z)^2-(1-z)^2=4z\ ,$$
wich proves that every point $(x,y,z)\in\ell$ is lying on the hyperbolic paraboloid given by $9x^2-25y^2=4z$.

Answer (score 2):

The intersection of the given planes is given by

$$\begin{cases}3x-5y-2z&=0\\{}\\3x+5y&=2\end{cases}\implies 10y+2z=2\implies 5y=-z+1\,,\,\,3x=2+z-1=z+1$$

and the line is

$$\left\{\,\left(\frac13(t+1),\,-\frac{t-1}5,\,t\right)\;/\;t\in\Bbb R\,\right\}=\left(\frac13,\,\frac15,\,0\right)+t\left(\frac13,\,-\frac15,\,1\right)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$$

Now, substitute values in the parabolloid's equation:

$$9\left[\frac13(t+1)\right]^2-25\left(\frac{t-1}5\right)^2\stackrel?=4t\iff(t+1)^2-(t-1)^2\stackrel?=4t\iff$$$${}$$

$$4t=4t\;\;\color{green}\checkmark$$

and since the last equality is trivially true we're done.